# Starting Prefect server on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, prefect

After installing [prefect](https://docs.prefect.io/2.10.15/getting-started/installation/#windows-installation-notes) version 2.10.15 and having the Scripts folder for python in my PATH variable I ran the command `prefect server start` to find the error:

```
 ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ _____
| _ \ _ \ __| __| __/ __|_   _|
|  _/   / _|| _|| _| (__  | |
|_| |_|_\___|_| |___\___| |_|

Configure Prefect to communicate with the server with:

    prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4200/api

View the API reference documentation at http://127.0.0.1:4200/docs

Check out the dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:4200



'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Server stopped!
```

This seems like an issue related to the Program Files folder (where python is installed), which does have this pesky space in its name. Is there a solution for this other than installing python elsewhere, specifically for running prefect server?

Comment: Usually quoting paths with spaces in them helps, but I have no idea how do you run the server.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I just installed prefect and ran `prefect server start`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like prefect just wanted to find the python executable and maybe some libraries and did it naively so it throws this error.

Using a virtualenv in a folder in a path without spaces fixed the problem.